# Issue in Extruding The Geometry

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, three.js, 2d

I am trying to Extrude the Rectangle drawn in the canvas to Three.js canvas.
Here Blue one is 2d canvas drawing and Green is 3d

[image]

```
  var Shape = new THREE.Shape();
    Shape.moveTo(0,0,0);

    for(var i=0;i<=point.length/2;i++)
    {
        Shape.lineTo(point[i],point[i+1]);
    }


    var ExtrusionSettings = {
        curveSegments: 3,
        bevelThickness:0, bevelSize: 0, bevelEnabled: false,
        material: 0, extrudeMaterial: 1,amount: 10
    };

    var Geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( Shape, ExtrusionSettings );
    var Material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff8800});
    Material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
    Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(Geometry,Material);
    Mesh.position.set(0,0,0);
    Scene.add(Mesh);
```

The points is passed as an array which contain the x,y coordinates of the lines in the canvas

the points are passed by

```
function mouseDown(event)
{
    Line[0] = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    Line[1] = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    console.log("down");

}

function mouseUp(event)
{
    Line[2] =  event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    Line[3] =  event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    console.log("up");

    var Width = Math.abs(Line[2] - Line[0]);
    var Height = Math.abs(Line[3] - Line[1]);



    Context.beginPath();
    //Context.moveTo(Line[0], Line[1]);
    //Context.lineTo(Line[2], Line[3]);

    //Context.rect(Line[0],Line[1],Width,Height);
     Context.lineWidth="5";
    Context.strokeStyle="red";


var L1P1x = Line[0];
var L1P1y = Line[1];
var L1P2x = Line[0]+Width;
var L1p2Y = Line[1];

var L2P1x = Line[0]+Width;
var L2P1y = Line[1];
var L2P2x = Line[2];
var L2P2y = Line[3];

var L3P1x = Line[2];
var L3P1y = Line[3];
var L3P2x = Line[0];
var L3P2y = Line[1]+Height;

var L4P1x = Line[0];
var L4P1y = Line[1]+Height;
var L4P2x = Line[0];
var L4P2y = Line[1];

Context.moveTo(L1P1x,L1P1y);
Context.lineTo(L1P2x,L1p2Y);
Context.moveTo(L2P1x,L2P1y);
Context.lineTo(L2P2x,L2P2y);
Context.moveTo(L3P1x,L3P1y);
Context.lineTo(L3P2x,L3P2y);
Context.moveTo(L4P1x,L4P1y);
Context.lineTo(L4P2x,L4P2y);

Context.stroke();

    Points.push(L1P1x,L1P1y,L1P2x,L1p2Y,L2P1x,L2P1y,L2P2x,L2P2y,L3P1x,L3P1y,L3P2x,L3P2y,L4P1x,L4P1y,L4P2x,L4P2y);
    addMesh(Points);//points are passes to draw in 3d
    //console.log(Points);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a fan of `three.js` but looking at your code you have some basic logic errors.

**The short answer**

Logic errors in the for loop! Change your first snippet to the following. You have `Points` in the second snippet and `Point` in the first. I have used `point` in the fix as I assume that is the correct name for the array of coordinates.

```
var i, len, mesh;      // define all the vars you will use
len = point.length;   // get the number of coordinates.
if(len > 1) {         // make sure there are points. 
    shape.moveTo(point[0], point[1]);          // move to the first point
    for(i = 2; i < len; i += 2) {              // iterate other points and lineTo them
       shape.lineTo(point[i], point[i + 1]);   // add the line.
    }
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(    // Create geom
            shape, 
            {    // extrusion settings.
                curveSegments   : 3,      
                bevelThickness  : 0,  
                bevelSize       : 0, 
                bevelEnabled    : false,
                material        : 0, 
                extrudeMaterial : 1,
                amount          : 10
            }
        ),      
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff8800}) // material
    );
    mesh.position.set(0, 0 0); // position the mesh  
    scene.add(mesh);           // add it to the scene
}
```

That will fix the bug. It was the for loop that was bad.

**The long answer.**

You seem to be a beginner so the long answer is to give you some longer term advice. (advice only as there are no rules).

Creating the shape. You had...

```
var Shape = new THREE.Shape();
Shape.moveTo(0,0,0);

for(var i=0;i<=point.length/2;i++)
{
    Shape.lineTo(point[i],point[i+1]);
}
```

Now with my pedantic eye

Never name vars with a capital. Capitaitals are reserved for named objects. Though in this case you are safe, using the name `Shape` in a differing scopy could well overwrite the object constructor.

```
var Shape = new THREE.Shape();  // you had
```

should be

```
var shape = new THREE.shape();
```

Capitals are only for objects that you can use the `new` token with, Acronyms, or constants. This is not a trivial convention as all of Javascript's inbuilt naming uses it and I have yet to find a popular framework that does not use it. DON'T CAPITALIZE, it is a bad habit in javascript and will cause endless hours looking for simple syntax bugs.

The THREE.Shape object only deals with 2D paths. You had

```
// 3 coordinates for for a 2D path???
Shape.moveTo(0,0,0);      // remove this line it is not needed
```

The last 0 is ignored, ( I checked the THREE.js source code) and that is not the error.

You error is here in the following.

```
for(var i=0;i<=point.length/2;i++)  // Only half the points ??
{   // you then line to x,y
    Shape.lineTo(point[i],point[i+1]);
    // Next lineTo will be y,x then x,y messing everything up.
}
```

`point` refers the the array of numbers representing the x and y coordinates of the path. It is organised with the `x` coord, then `y` then `x` then `y`.

The number of items in the array is the number of 2D points * 2. The * 2 is because there is a `X` and a ``Y for each point.

So need to iterate the point array correctly.

**Step by step.**

```
var i, len;  // always put your vars declarations at the top
len = point.length;  // I like to get the length before the loop.
```

The `for` loop needs to step by 2 as the are two entries for each point.

```
for(i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {   //Put the { at the end. Saves space and is easier to read.
```

Check for the first point as you need to `moveTo` (note answer is slightly different)

```
if(i === 0) {
```

Add the point to the path (shape).

```
    shape.moveTo(point[i], point[i + 1]);
```

Then the other points

```
} else {
    shape.lineTo(point[i], point[i + 1]);
}
```

This will create the correct shape that you can then use to extrude.

Put all together as I would do it.

```
// where do you define scene. It should be lowercase
var i, len, mesh; 
len = point.length;  
if(len > 1) {                          // check if there are points (2 or more.
    shape.moveTo(point[0], point[1]);  // do the first point outside the for loop
                                       // this saves having to do the if statement
                                       // for each point
    for(i = 2; i < len; i += 2) {      // iterate points starting at the second
       shape.moveTo(point[i], point[i + 1]);   // add the line.
    }
```

You had

```
    // Such a long name for a one of abd just a mess
    // Your code 
    //var ExtrusionSettings = {
    //    curveSegments: 3,
    //    bevelThickness:0, bevelSize: 0, bevelEnabled: false,
    //    material: 0, extrudeMaterial: 1,amount: 10
    //};
    // unless it will be used again put it inline

    // Bad naming for the rest
    // Your code
    //var Geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( Shape, ExtrusionSettings );
    //var Material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff8800});
    //Material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
    //Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(Geometry,Material);
    //Mesh.position.set(0,0,0);
    //Scene.add(Mesh);
```

Replace it all with

```
    // Material is used once so no need to create var for it
    // Removed Material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;  // assuming this is debug code only
    // you had Mesh without var. That made it global scope. Never use a var without defining it first with the var token

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(  // define and assign mesh
        new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(    // Create geom// indent arguments for readability
            shape, 
            {    // extrusion settings.
                curveSegments   : 3,      // line it all up so you can read it quickly
                bevelThickness  : 0,  
                bevelSize       : 0, 
                bevelEnabled    : false,
                material        : 0, 
                extrudeMaterial : 1,
                amount          : 10
            }
        ),      
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff8800})
    );

    mesh.position.set(0,0,0);  // position the mesh

    scene.add(mesh);  // add it to the scene
    // note the lowercase scene for the object instance scene. Need to chage that where you create it.    
} // end of if(len > 1){
```

There is a lot of pedantic stuff there but you are clearly new to programming and bad habits are hard to break so start with good ones. Bugs and debugging are the worst part of programming. Debugging is the single most time consuming part of all programming (even for experienced professionals). The single biggest cause of bugs in all programing languages is bad style and or messy code. Writing clean consistent code makes your code easier to read and hence easier to debug. Try finding a missing `{` in 5000 lines of `{''s or a capital where a lowercase character should be (Hours debugging code while the simple error is right in front of you hidden in a mess can make or break being a coder)

Hope this helped..